# Time Sheet in Field Service Lightning

Tags: service-cloud-console, service

I am pretty about use of TimeSheet in Field Service Lightning, am not sure who will create this record and manage this. Ideally this should be enter by mobile resource but i read somewhere that this might be managed by Dispatcher.

I am very much confused about this feature in Field Service Lightning.

Please let me know if someone has worked on this and what would be the ideal scenarios.

Comment: Good question i would like to know the best practice too on this one.